# Insert formatted text to Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, formatting

I insert text to a Word document. This is done by  `selection.TypeText("text");`

I would like to insert **formatted** text to a Word document, something like:

```
public override void InsertText(string content, string format)
{
    selection.Style = format; //something like this
    selection.Font.Name = "Heading 1"; //or like this
    selection.TypeText(content);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For a Word Document-Level Customization where `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` is referenced, this works:

```
this.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
this.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Font.Size = 36;
```

You can also assign the range of a selection to a range variable and then apply formats to the variable as in:

```
Word.Range myRange = this.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range;
myRange.Font.Size = 18;
myRange.Font.Name = "Arial";
```

**EDIT (Response to OP's question in comments)**

To apply a Heading style to the selected text assign one of Word's `WdBuiltinStyle` enumeration members:

```
object headingStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1;
this.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.set_Style(ref headingStyle);
```

To view the full list of enumeration members, see this:

[MSDN: WdBuiltinStyle enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbuiltinstyle(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I would like to set the text to be formatted to Heading 1, Heading 2, etc. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please see the additional information that I added to my answer.

Comment: FYI if the range contains multiple fonts this will crash.

Comment: @Rob Great comment. I just experienced that. In my use case, I am looking to replace a range in one document with a range from another (using the format from the text that is to be pasted in). Do you have any ideas about how one might replace the text with formatting? I've considered replacing the text with nothing and simply inserting the range, but have not been able to do that yet.

Comment: @MatthewKligerman  Did you try pastewithformatting?

Comment: @Rob That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!